# Dragging on an element on top of an element with -webkit-overflow-scrolling causes underlying element to scroll

Tags: css

I've only noticed this on iOS. Haven't tested on android.

If a non-scrollable element overlays an element with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`, if you drag on the top element, the element underneath scrolls.

I've also noticed that `overscroll-behavior: contain;` doesn't seem to work if the element underneath has `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

Can someone explain what the issue is and how to keep the bottom element from scrolling when dragging on the top element?

Here's a codepen - https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NJWvVZ

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin:0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #c00;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: green;
  width: 50vw;
  z-index: 1;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <p>aside</p>
  <p>aside</p>
  <p>aside</p>
  <p>aside</p>
  <p>aside</p>
  <p>aside</p>
</aside>
<section>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
  <p>section</p>
</section>
```